# Unable to login to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04

```
run parts: failed to exec /etc/update-motd.d/99-livepatch-kernel-upgrade-required: No such file or directory
run parts: etc/update-motd.d/99-livepatch-kernel-upgrade-required exited with return code 1
Last login: Fri Aug 4 15:24:40 IST 2023 on tty1
```

output of `uname -r` :

```
6.2.0-26-generic
```

No other OS. The computer is a Dell Precision 5530.

I have been using Linux since about 10 years. I'm not a command-line expert. I have been mostly troubleshooting problems by googling. I tried downgrading to an earlier kernel, but it didn't work.